# How to pass policyKey to Brightcove react-player-loader?

Tags: brightcove, player-loader, react-player-loader, policykey

I'm trying to use [Brightcove react-player-loader](https://github.com/brightcove/react-player-loader), but there doesn't seem to be any documented way to pass the policyKey to the player. Brightcove has a [web page](https://apis.support.brightcove.com/playback/getting-started/quick-start-playback-api.html) where you can test assets using a Codepen. It requires accountId, videoId and policyKey. My test asset can be accessed on that web page, so I know it works, but how do I use the policyKey with react-player-loader? There is no mention of policyKey in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set it with `player.catalog.setPolicyKey(MY_POLICY_KEY)` on the initialised player, whcih you access in an `onSuccess` handler. This only works with an "in-page" and not an iframe type embed.

```js
function (success) {
  const player = success.ref;
  player.ready(function () {
    player.catalog.setPolicyKey('abcd...');
    player.catalog.get({type: 'video', id: '1234'}).then(player.catalog.load);
  });
}
```